# Converter time stamp em data completa com php

Tags: php, timestamp

Temho no meu banco um campo com `timestamp datetime` e preciso converter o `timestamp` para este formato **exemplo**:

> QUARTA-FEIRA, 31 DE DEZEMBRO DE 1969 postado às 15:30

pesquisei por aqui e achei um código, mas não consigo fazer funcionar o mesmo retorna um erro:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_BR', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'portuguese');
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
$var_DateTime = $dd;
return utf8_encode(ucwords(strftime('%A', $var_DateTime->sec)).', '
    .strftime('%d', $var_DateTime->sec).
    ' de '.ucwords(strftime('%B', $var_DateTime->sec))
    .' de '.strftime('%Y', $var_DateTime->sec));
```

Como formatar esta data?

Answer (score 3):

Se o timestamp está certinho vai rolar assim:

```
return utf8_encode(
    strtoupper(
    strftime('%A, %e de %B de %Y postado às %H:%M', 
        $var_DateTime->sec)
    ));
```

Comment: deu o emsmo erro  NOTICE: TRYING TO GET PROPERTY OF NON-OBJECT IN E:\WAMP64\WWW\DAGAZ\SITE\ESSENCIALS\CONNECTION.INC.PHP ON LINE 170

Comment: meu time stamp esta assim  2016-10-25 22:36:52

Comment: o erro não tem a ver com esse código, ele tá dizendo que `$var_DateTime` não é um objeto, por isso não consegue pegar a propriedade `sec`

Comment: O que o Ricardo disse é verdade. Você tem que contextualizar melhor a pergunta caso isso não seja o problema em questão @JasarOrion. O código dele funcionaria corretamente. Só acho que talvez seja desnecessário usar o `utf8_encode` nesse caso, mas é a solução para seu problema da data.

Comment: Acredito, então, pelo comentário, poderia corrigir essa resposta transformando o valor para o respectivo tipo de dado (`DateTime`) pelo que pude perceber.

Comment: e qual seria de acordo com o time stamp que esta no db ? e o $var_DateTime->sec se eu colocar apenas $var_DateTime ele diz que não é uma data valida. ( non well formed number )

Comment: Coloca `var_dump( $var_DateTime );` logo antes do `return` e cola aqui o que ele imprime na tela.

Answer (score 0):

Se a sua data vem assim `2016-10-25 22:36:52`, então:

```
<?php

setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_BR', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'portuguese');

$data = strtotime('2016-10-25 22:36:52');

echo utf8_encode(
    strtoupper(
    strftime('%A, %e de %B de %Y postado às %H:%M', 
        $data)
    ));
```

Answer (score -2):

achei uma função que resolveu meu problema

```
function dataEmPortugues ($timestamp, $hours = FALSE, $timeZone = "Europe/Lisbon") {

    $dia_num = date("w", $timestamp);// Dia da semana.

    if($dia_num == 0){
    $dia_nome = "Domingo";
    }elseif($dia_num == 1){
    $dia_nome = "Segunda";
    }elseif($dia_num == 2){
    $dia_nome = "Terça";
    }elseif($dia_num == 3){
    $dia_nome = "Quarta";
    }elseif($dia_num == 4){
    $dia_nome = "Quinta";
    }elseif($dia_num == 5){
    $dia_nome = "Sexta";
    }else{
    $dia_nome = "Sábado";
    }

    $dia_mes = date("d", $timestamp);// Dia do mês

    $mes_num = date("m", $timestamp);// Nome do mês

    if($mes_num == 01){
    $mes_nome = "Janeiro";
    }elseif($mes_num == 02){
    $mes_nome = "Fevereiro";
    }elseif($mes_num == 03){
    $mes_nome = "Março";
    }elseif($mes_num == 04){
    $mes_nome = "Abril";
    }elseif($mes_num == 05){
    $mes_nome = "Maio";
    }elseif($mes_num == 06){
    $mes_nome = "Junho";
    }elseif($mes_num == 07){
    $mes_nome = "Julho";
    }elseif($mes_num == 08){
    $mes_nome = "Agosto";
    }elseif($mes_num == 09){
    $mes_nome = "Setembro";
    }elseif($mes_num == 10){
    $mes_nome = "Outubro";
    }elseif($mes_num == 11){
    $mes_nome = "Novembro";
    }else{
    $mes_nome = "Dezembro";
    }
    $ano = date("Y", $timestamp);// Ano

    date_default_timezone_set($timeZone); // Set time-zone
    $hora = date ("H:i", $timestamp);

    if ($hours) {
        return $dia_nome.", ".$dia_mes." de ".$mes_nome." de ".$ano." - ".$hora;
    }
    else {
        return $dia_nome.", ".$dia_mes." de ".$mes_nome." de ".$ano;
    }
}

echo dataEmPortugues(strtotime("2014-07-17 21:49:23"), TRUE, "America/Sao_Paulo");
```

Comment: -1 A solução abaixo resolve perfeitamente o problema, além desse código aí  ter uma complicação desnecessária.